# Structure Azure Devops for two projects with shared codebase

Tags: azure-devops

I have two different software projects that both share the same codebase. We are just learning azure devops and so would like to know the best way to structure the Project within devops.

Comment: Are you hosting your code base in GitHub or azure repo. I suggest you separate your software project codebase if it is possible and create different azure repos and development teams to manage them.  If the projects cannot be in separate code repo. you can still manage them in a single azure repo with different development team in your azure devops project. When you build and publish your software, you can create different azure pipelines for them.

Comment: Hosted repo in Azure. Thanks for the advice - I'll be using the single project with multiple teams approach